# One Hot Encoding in Tensor flow for Batch Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding, mini-batch

My training data contains ~1500 labels(string,one label per record) and I want to do batch training (just load one batch into memory to update weights in a neural network). I was wondering if there is a class in tensorflow to do one hot encoding for the labels in each batch? Something like in sklearn we can do

```
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
onehot_encoder.fit(entire training labels)
```

And then in each batch in tensorflow session, I can transform my batch label and feed into tensorflow for traning

```
batch_label = onehot_encoder.transform(batch training labels)
sess.run(feed_dict={x:...,y:batch_label)
```

An example will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to do a classifier without doing the one-hot encoding. You can use the sparse_cross_entropy_with_logits.

Comment: @Aaron I guess both the label and logits in the function must have shape of [None,Number of Classes]?. However, my data now is one label per record

Comment: That's not true. Look at the sparse cross entropy function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post is similar to that one [Tensorflow One Hot Encoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681517/tensorflow-one-hot-encoder)

A sort answer from this link  http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot

```
indices = [0, 1, 2]
depth = 3
tf.one_hot(indices, depth)  
# output: [3 x 3]
# [[1., 0., 0.],
#  [0., 1., 0.],
#  [0., 0., 1.]]
```

Just posting it to save your time ;)