# In a two class issue with one-hot label, why tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy outputs very large cost

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a mobilenet for semantic segmentation on tf. The targets has two classes: *foreground(1)* or *background(0)*. So this is a two class classification issue.
I choose softmax cross entropy as the loss, using python code like:

```
tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(self.targets, logits)
```

Size of targets and logits is `[batch_size, 224, 224, 2]`. However, the loss becomes very big after 100 batches, curve is like this:

[image]

From tf's api docus, I know that `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` has [batch_size, num_classes] target one-hot-encoded labels, which coincides with my label with size of `[batch_size,224,224,2]`, either 1 or 0 (which is exclusive).
So, softmax_cross_entropy can't be used in a two class one-hot label case like this and why? If it can be used, where is my problem?

If I use `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy` or `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`(only give label size: `[batch_size, 224,224,1]`), the loss will converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input targets format for `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` and  `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` is different.

> - For `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` labels must have the    shape
>     [batch_size] and the dtype int32 or int64. Each label is an int    in
>     range [0, num_classes-1].
> - For `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`,    labels must have the shape [batch_size, num_classes] and dtype    float32 or float64.
>
> Labels used in `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` are the one hot
>   version of labels used in `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

Reference: [TensorFlow: what's the difference between sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits and softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312421/tensorflow-whats-the-difference-between-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logi)

So, to make it work using `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, you will have to do [tf.one_hot](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) on the labels.

Comment: The labels do have difference. But sigmoid_cross_entropy should has a label size [batch_size, num_classes], refer to this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sigmoid_cross_entropy.

Actually, from tf's api_doc, sigmoid_cross_entropy and softmax_cross_entropy have the same label size, the difference is if the label is exclusive.
In my case, I gave a label size of [batch_size, 224, 224, 2] for a two class classification, each pixel can be 1 or 0, but can be 1 at the same time, which is one-hot. So I think one-hot label can be used for the two function, but not work.

Comment: You are right about the sigmoid_cross_entropy, it was a mistake on my side, I have updated my answer. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681517/tensorflow-one-hot-encoder