# Implementing Dice Lose

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I would like to implement Dice Lose like this from [dice_loss_for_keras.py](https://gist.github.com/wassname/7793e2058c5c9dacb5212c0ac0b18a8a):

```
from keras import backend as K

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
    """
    Dice = (2*|X & Y|)/ (|X|+ |Y|)
         =  2*sum(|A*B|)/(sum(A^2)+sum(B^2))
    ref: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04797v1.pdf
    """
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(K.square(y_true),-1) + K.sum(K.square(y_pred),-1) + smooth)
```

The only problem is that, in most UNET implementation,  y_true have 1 channel while y_pred have 3 channels (for example for 3 classes) because y_pred is represented by hot vector.
Is there away either to convert y_true like  y_pred or vice versa or make the output of UNET as 1 channel like y_true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `y_true` to 1-hot representation in order to apply per-class dice loss.
It seems like you have [`tf.one_hot`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33681517/1714410) function that does it for you.

Once you have `y_true` in the same shape as `y_pred`, you can use your code to compute the dice score *for each class* separately, and then combine the scores of all classes to get the final scalar loss.